# SQLAlchemy ORM function works in main script but fails in Pytest

Tags: sqlalchemy, pytest, python-3.7

Using Postgres, SQLAlchemy 1.4 ORM, Python 3.7, Pytest.

I have a script in `myproject/src/db.py` and the tests for it are located in `myproject/tests/`.

In `db.py` I have a function to drop any given table, it works as expected:

```
async def delete_table(self, table_name):
    table = self.meta.tables[table_name]
    async with self.engine.begin() as conn:
       await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.drop_all(sync_engine, [table], checkfirst=True))
```

It gets called like:
`asyncio.run(db.delete_table('user'))`

In `conftest.py` I have a fixture like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def test_drop_table():
    def get_delete_tables(table_name):
        return asyncio.run(DB.delete_table(table_name))
    return get_delete_tables
```

In `test.py` I run the test like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('function_input, expected',
                         [('user', 'user'),
                          pytest.param('intentional failure', 'intentional failure',
                                       marks=pytest.mark.xfail(reason='testing incorrect table name fails'))])
def test_drop_table(test_drop_table, function_input, expected):
    # Drop the table
    test_drop_table(function_input)
    
    # Check that it no longer exists
    with pytest.raises(KeyError) as error_info:
        test_table_commits(function_input, expected)
        raise KeyError
    assert error_info.type is KeyError
```

When I run this test I get this error:

```
self = <postgresdb.PostgresDb object at 0x7f4bbd87cc18>, table_name = 'user'

    async def delete_table(self, table_name):
>       table = self.meta.tables[table_name]
E       KeyError: 'user'
```

I verified that this table can be dropped in the main script. I then recommit the table, verify it is present, and then try to drop it with the test but will continually receive a `KeyError` that the table is not present even though when checking the database that table is actually present.

I'm not sure what to test or adjust in the code to get Pytest working with this function. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

I think for the first time it deletes the table named `user`, but the second input in `pytest.mark.parametrize` is also the name `user`, so it may be throwing error. If you need to test 2 different scenarios, it's better to have 2 different test functions. By doing this, you can have all your code under `with pytest.raises(KeyError) as error_info` in the 2nd test function.